# Slim form not posting with smart characters and the word "from"

Tags: php, ajax, slim

I have a form that most users will paste content from emails, so this of course has a bunch of special/smart characters because of Outlook. Because of this I am using JS code to replace the characters before it is submitted via ajax post. I also JSON.stringify it. I am on SLIM v3 so it does go through a route to a controller file and then ultimately a service file. At the service file it has a json_decode and then it has any special/smart characters removed again. Then it is saved to the DB.  Also I am using PDO with prepared statements and that the issue only exists on centos apache, but not in my local Windows dev environment.

My problem is that some content will save and some content will not. The only commonality for not saving is that sometimes the content has the word "from" in it. When I change to word "from" to "From" it will save.

It is hard to pinpoint where it is failing because the only error I get is "Method not allowed. Must be one of: POST" which my JS is using post and the route in Slim knows to expect post.

The replacing of characters twice and the stringify may seem overkill but I just wanted to cover my bases.

I am looking for any suggestions to try.

Here is the JS to replace the Microsoft characters. I found it on stackoverflow.

```
cleanText: function(text) {
var s = text;
// smart single quotes and apostrophe
s = s.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/g, "\'");
// smart double quotes
s = s.replace(/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g, "\"");
// ellipsis
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
// dashes
s = s.replace(/[\u2013\u2014]/g, "-");
// circumflex
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
// open angle bracket
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
// close angle bracket
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
// spaces
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC\u00A0]/g, " ");

return s;
}
```

Here is where I stringify it:

```
collectFieldValues: function() {
var params = {
record: this.settings.record,
module: this.settings.module,
note: JSON.stringify(Notes.cleanText($('#mn-note').val())),
noteID: $('#note_id').val(),
visibility: $('#mn-visibility').val(),
};
return params;
},
```

Here is the PHP insert code:

```
public function insert($table, $data, $display = false, $execute = true) {
    $fields = $this->filter($table, $data);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode($fields, ", ") . ") VALUES (:" . implode($fields, ", :") . ");";
    $bind = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $bind[":$field"] = $data[$field];
    }

    if ($this->run($sql, $bind, $display, $execute) !== false) {
        return intval($this->lastInsertId());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is where the params get collected before the insert:

```
        $note = $this->target->insert('notes', [
        "linkID"     => $this->app->hasher->decode($attributes['record']),
        'type'       => $attributes['module'],
        'visibility' => $attributes['visibility'],
        'note'       => $this->cleanText(json_decode($attributes['note'], true)),
        'created'    => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'author'     => $userID,
    ]);
```

Here is the PHP code that cleans up the text before it goes to the db. Is there something more comprehensive? I tried using the neitanod/forceutf8 package but that did not help.

```
    public function cleanText($string)
{
    $search = [                 // www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/<NUM>/ <NUM> = 2018
                    "\xC2\xAB",     // « (U+00AB) in UTF-8
                    "\xC2\xBB",     // » (U+00BB) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x98", // ‘ (U+2018) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x99", // ’ (U+2019) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9A", // ‚ (U+201A) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9B", // ? (U+201B) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9C", // “ (U+201C) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9D", // ” (U+201D) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9E", // „ (U+201E) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x9F", // ? (U+201F) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\xB9", // ‹ (U+2039) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\xBA", // › (U+203A) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x93", // – (U+2013) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\x94", // — (U+2014) in UTF-8
                    "\xE2\x80\xA6"  // … (U+2026) in UTF-8
        ];

        $replacements = [
                    "<<",
                    ">>",
                    "'",
                    "'",
                    "'",
                    "'",
                    '"',
                    '"',
                    '"',
                    '"',
                    "<",
                    ">",
                    "-",
                    "-",
                    "..."
        ];

    return str_replace($search, $replacements, $string);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code in question? The form, the javascript handler, and the PHP processing it?

Comment: That is all the code I can copy in. I use Slim so the code is ultimately in 10 different places and it is a bit of a pain to get at.

Comment: Why not skip all that sanitizing and just encode to base64.